# WHY is $\operatorname{supp}(τ_hf) =h + \operatorname{supp}(f)$ ??

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, compactness, distribution-theory

Why is $\operatorname{supp}(τ_hf) =h + \operatorname{supp}(f)$?

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Define $τ_hf$  by $(τ_hf)(x)=f(x-h)$ translation of $f$ by $h$.

Prove $\operatorname{supp}(τ_hf) =h + \operatorname{supp}(f)$

I'm trying to understand why this happens.

I am trying to prove by double inclusion. Let $A =\operatorname{supp}(τ_hf)$ and $B = h + \operatorname{supp}(f)$ .

I took an element in $A$ and I can't get that this element is also in $B$. (In similar way if I take an element in $B$ I can't get to $A$.) I don't know if I'm going the right way in this prove.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this prove or give me some idea how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: It should be $\tau_h$.

Comment: $x \in \operatorname{supp}f \Leftrightarrow f(x) \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow f((x + h) - h) \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow (\tau _h f)(x + h) \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow x + h \in \operatorname{supp}(\tau _h f)$

Comment: @Gary the first and last equivalence are not true (since the supports are defined as the closures), but of course, taking the closures of the remaining relations yields the proof.

Comment: I couldn't resist repairing the $x,h$ confusion...

Comment: @peek-a-boo You are right, my bad. Thanks for the comment.